# JSF primefaces showing list of object not list of string

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I already tried to search through this site, but maybe I'm not getting understand well.
Please kindly advice for my cases..

I'm using Netbeans 7.3 + Primefaces + Hibernate.
I want to show a list from my query.

My query already in.. and there's no error showup, but the display is not what I want (I think it returning an object or something, not sure).

Please kindly correct me if I'm missed something.

Here's my PtlLovBean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ptlLovBean")
@SessionScoped

public class PtlLovBean implements Serializable {
private static final String FLIGHT = "LOV_FLIGHT";

private List lovFlight;

public List getLovFlight() {
    PtlLovDao ptlLovDao = new PtlLovDaoImpl();
    return ptlLovDao.getByKey(FLIGHT);
}    
}
```

Here's ptlLovDao

```
public interface PtlLovDao {

public List getByKey(String key);

}
```

Here's PtlLovDaoImpl

```
public class PtlLovDaoImpl implements PtlLovDao {

@Override
public List getByKey(String key) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from PtlLov where LOV_KEY = :param");
    query.setParameter("param", key);                
    return query.list();
}
}
```

Here's my JSF :

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="flightName" value="#{wizard.user.selectedFlightName}"> 
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Flight" itemValue="" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{ptlLovBean.lovFlight}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Display after Code:

Sorry I'm not capable to insert picture, so here's the image link : 
http://i117.photobucket.com/albums/o56/po_se_for/PIC_zps88ec4983.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either override the `toString` method in your `PtlLov` class or define `itemValue` and `itemLabel` properties in your `f:selectItems` tag.

Something like this:

```html
<f:selectItems value="#{ptlLovBean.lovFlight}" var="flight"
    itemValue="#{flight}" itemLabel="#{flight.description}" />
```

Comment: thanks @RodrigoSasaki
already change my jsf like this : 
<f:selectItems var="flight" value="#{ptlLovBean.ptlLovs}" itemValue="#{flight}" itemLabel="#{flight.label}"/>